# Edit existing Camera Raw Filter

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, color-profile, adobe-lightroom, adobe-camera-raw

I'm looking for a way to **edit a Camera Raw Filter** that I've already created and want to modify or just know how it was created. I couldn't find any way to do that.

**What I do** is selecting the Camera Raw Filter option in Photoshop. Then I do all the edits, and when I like it, I save it as a profile to use it in Lightroom afterward.

**I'd like to know how some of the profiles I have were exactly created**, and modify some I have without creating them from scratch or overriding them in the Camera Raw Filter creation (I mean, applying the profile from the start, do some edits, and save it under another name).

Does anyone know how to edit or see the edits on them?

Answer (score 0):

You can load, change, re-save settings in the Photoshop Raw Filter.

[image]

To view the changes made:

> Adjustments made in Camera Raw are also displayed in the Adobe Bridge
>   Content and Preview panels.
>
> To view Lightroom changes in Camera Raw, and to ensure that Camera Raw
>   adjustments can be viewed in Lightroom and Adobe Bridge, do the
>   following:
>
> 1. In Adobe Bridge, choose Edit > Camera Raw Preferences (Windows) or
>      Bridge > Camera Raw Preferences (Mac OS). Or, with the Camera Raw
>      dialog box open, click the Open Preferences Dialog button.
> 2. Choose Save Image Settings In > Sidecar “.XMP” Files, and deselect
>      Ignore Sidecar “.XMP” Files.
> 3. After applying adjustments to a photo in
>      Camera Raw, save them by clicking Done or Open Image.

Source: https://helpx.adobe.com/camera-raw/using/introduction-camera-raw.html

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your image to a Smart Object before applying the Adobe Camera RAW filter, you can double click the filter in the Layers panel, to open the Camera RAW filter to edit the adjustments you made.

In the example below, Layer 1 is a Smart Object, and so the Camera RAW Filter is added as a Smart Filter

[image]